# SolidJS: For in child component not rendering list

Tags: solid-js

I have a parent component returning:

```
<List list={list()}>
    {(item, index) => <div>{item}</div>}
</List>
```

where `list` is a created signal. `List` is a custom component I made returning:

```
<div>
    <For each={list}>{children}</For>
</div>
```

but whenever `list` is updated, it isn't rendered. When I move the `For` code to the parent, it renders, so what is it about passing a signal's value to a child component that makes it not rerender on updates?

EDIT: [demo](https://playground.solidjs.com/?hash=-1957994756&version=1.3.3)

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, For } from "solid-js";

function Counter() {
  const [list, setList] = createSignal([]);
  const increment = () => setList([...list(), 1]);

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={increment}>
        add
      </button>
      <p>broken list</p>
      <List list={list()} />

      <p>other list</p>
      <For each={list()}>
        {(item) => <p>{item}</p>}
      </For>
    </>
  );
}

function List({list}) {
  return (
    <For each={list}>
      {(item) => <p>{item}</p>}
    </For>
  );
}

render(() => <Counter />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

EDIT 2: I meant to use `<List list={list()} />`, which also doesn't work, but I missed it earlier.

Comment: The demo is just default solid playground code, can you include the actual code in playground please?

Comment: added my demo code and link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not work because destructuring `props` in Solid loses reactivity, that is, all the destructured props values do not update, ever.

Destructuring `props` is sometimes convenient and commonly used in other frameworks, but is not really recommended in Solid - the [FAQ](https://www.solidjs.com/guides/faq#why-doesn%27t-destructuring-work-with-props-or-stores%3F) says:

> By destructuring, you separate the value from the object, giving you the value at that point in time and losing reactivity.

You need to rewrite `List` component to use single `props` parameter and access `props.list` in the JSX:

```js
function List(props) {
  return (
    <For each={props.list}>
      {(item) => <p>{item}</p>}
    </For>
  );
}
```

Why destructuring does not work? In Solid, `props` is an object, created behind the scenes by Solid, with getters for intercepting access to each individual property, like `props.something`. It's needed to track JSX (expressions and fragments) and effects (created by `createEffect()`) so that they are reevaluated and updated when `props.something` changes. There's no way to track access to properties which are destructured (well there's [plugin for that](https://github.com/orenelbaum/babel-plugin-solid-undestructure), but it's not in the core framework because it has some overhead).

Comment: Sorry I meant to type `<List list={list()} />`. Could you edit your answer to explain why that  doesn't work?

Comment: sure, I updated the answer